# Why Can't I get this Svg accent bar to shrink on javascript event listener

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, mouseevent

I have been trying to get this working for around two hours and cannot,
seem to figure out how to do it. I've tried every combination that I can think of
and read some article & questions but its still not changeing
on `mousedown` or `mouseclick` Code is below:
[image]
HTML

```
<!-- ::.....::>> Remake in Svg Format. <<::.......:: -->
<div id="Burger">
    <div class="menu">
      <input type="checkbox" name="menu-active" id="menu-active">
      <div class="items first">
        <div class="i-1">Home</div>
        <div class="i-2">About</div>
      </div>
      <label for="menu-active">
        <div class="lines">
          <div class="line-1"></div>
          <div class="line-2"></div>
          <div class="line-3"></div>
        </div>
      </label>
      <div class="items last">
        <div class="i-3">Services</div>
        <div class="i-4">Contact</div>
      </div>
      <i class="blob"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="svg_cont">
<svg id="Hue_bar" viewBox="0 0 208.51721 1.5955585" version="1.1"
                 width="208.51721mm" height="1.5955585mm" style="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                 sodipodi:docname="hue_space_bar.svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1"
                 xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
                 xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
                 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
                 inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)"
                 xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#">
                <defs id="defs2"/>
                <sodipodi:namedview id="base" pagecolor="#ffffff" bordercolor="#666666"
                                    borderopacity="1.0" inkscape:pageopacity="0.0" inkscape:pageshadow="2"
                                    inkscape:zoom="0.98994949" inkscape:cx="396.84993" inkscape:cy="45.208726"
                                    inkscape:document-units="mm" inkscape:current-layer="layer1" showgrid="false"
                                    inkscape:window-width="1288" inkscape:window-height="754" inkscape:window-x="156"
                                    inkscape:window-y="156" inkscape:window-maximized="0"/>
                      <metadata id="metadata5">
                        <rdf:RDF>
                          <cc:Work rdf:about="">
                            <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
                            <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
                            <dc:title/>
                          </cc:Work>
                        </rdf:RDF>
                      </metadata>
              <g inkscape:label="Layer 1" inkscape:groupmode="layer" id="layer1" transform="translate(-0.41000891,-0.47546211)">
                <image id="image3721" width="208.51721" height="1.5955585" x="0.41000891" y="0.47546211"
                       xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,Redacted:Base64Image"
        style="image-rendering:optimizeQuality"
        preserveAspectRatio="none" decoding="async"/>
      </g>
</svg>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }
* body {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  place-items: center;  
  background-color: black;
  image-rendering: smooth;
  font-family: 'Syne Tactile', cursive;
  color: #adb5bd;    
  }
* body input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
  }
#Burger{
    position:absolute;
    top:;left:8vw;
    width:488px;
    height:97px;
    background:green;
    padding:18px 0 27px 24px;
    background:linear-gradient(-33deg,black,black);
    }
.lines {
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1;
  }
.lines [class^="line-"] {
  width: 60px;
  height: 8px;
  background: linear-gradient(-33deg,
        springgreen, mediumvioletred,
           deeppink);
  box-shadow: 0 0 7.2px 2.7px springgreen;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;    
  border-radius: 4.2px;    
  will-change: auto;    
  margin: 10px 0;
  }
#menu-active:checked ~ label .line-1 {
  transform: translatey(18px) rotate(45deg);
  background: linear-gradient(-33deg, gold, red, red, gold); z-index:8;
  /* width:18px; height:12.8px;*/
  /*  height:12.8px;*/
  box-shadow: 0 0 7.2px 2.7px red;
  }
#menu-active:checked ~ label .line-2 {
  transform: scale(0) rotateZ(3240deg);
  transition: all 887ms ease-in 84ms;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7.2px 64.7px red;
  z-index:7;
  }
#menu-active:checked ~ label .line-3 {
  transform: translatey(-18px) rotate(-45deg);
  background: linear-gradient(-33deg, gold, red, orange, gold); z-index:8;
  box-shadow: 0 0 7.2px 2.7px red;
  }
.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  
  }
label {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  }
.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;    
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-weight: 600;    
  transition: all 0.6s ease;    
  z-index: 0;
  }
.items [class^="i-"] {
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding:1.8px;    
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  background:linear-gradient(-33deg,red,gold);
  font-size:calc(18px + 1.27vw);
  filter:blur(0.575px);
  background-clip:text;
  color:transparent;
  }
.items [class^="i-"]:hover {
  background:linear-gradient(134deg,#b8f406,green,blue);
  transition:all 428ms ease-in 2ms;
  text-shadow:0px 12.4px 1.54px springgreen;
  background-clip:text;
  color:transparent;
  }
.first {
  transform: translatex(100px);
  pointer-events: none;  
  opacity: 0%;
  }
.last {
  transform: translatex(-100px);
  pointer-events: none;    
  opacity: 0%;
  }
#menu-active:checked ~ .first {
  transform: translatex(0px);
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 100%;
  }
#menu-active:checked ~ .last {
  transform: translatex(0px);
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 100%;
  }
.blob {
  position: absolute;
  top:50%; left:50%;    
  width: 22px; height: 22px;    
  transform: translate(-124%, -254%);    
  background: springgreen;
  filter: blur(2.88px);    
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index:7;
  }
.blob:before{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    border-radius:50%; left:80px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:2px;
    box-shadow:inset -2px 2px 4px 18px darkblue;       background:skyblue;
    }     /* width:22px; height:22px; */
.svg_cont{
    position:absolute; height:8px;
    top:64%; left:calc(0.04vw + 108px);
    width:790px; overflow:hidden;
    }
#Hue_bar{
    position:absolute;
    top:0%; left:calc(0);
    transition:width 288ms ease-in-out 4ms;    
    transform:translate(0%);
    }
```

Javascript

```
let qS =(s)=>{
    return document.querySelector(s);
    }

let toggle   = qS('#menu-active');
let svg_cont = qS('.svg_cont');
let hue      = qS('#Hue_bar');

toggle.addEventListener("mousedown",(e)=>{
       svg_cont.contentDocument.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","width", "20px");
});
```

& The Codepen Example is here:
https://codepen.io/MistaKisthur/pen/dyXropM

I would like for the Svg Bar element to respond to when the checkbox is ticked, So when the Nav menu is open the svg is full width, inline with the text. Then when its clicked again it shrinks it x width to around 20/40px

I have tried `setAttribute`, `style.transform`, `setting it width`, adding `!important`, wrapping it in a div, setting this to overflow hidden and then trying to shrink that element instead. Tried inline inside the svg, tried elem.setAttributeNS() function, Tried adding or removing classes & tried `elem.contentDocument` None of them are having any effect what so ever on the inline svg.. Have i missed something really stupid of messed up in my code where i can't see it..

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a few things wrong:

1. The event is `"click"`, not `"mouseclick"`.
2. `qS('.svg_cont')` returns a single DOM element, not an array. So `svg_cont[0]` (as you have in your codepen), is invalid.
3. `contentDocument` only applies to elements like `<iframe>` and `<object>`. Not `<div>`.

If you want to change the `width` of the SVG, there are several ways you could do it. For instance:

```
let svg_cont = qS('.svg_cont svg');

toggle.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
       svg_cont.setAttribute("width", "20px");
});
```

Comment: mousedown isa valid event listener though, i tried the code you put above but still didn't work.. wrapped the arrow function in parethesis and its working, but only for the first click, checking the dom tree, the input checkbox isn't changing any value when its checked or unchecked? thought this was added as an attribute when-ever it is selected..

Comment: Setting the width is a one-way operation. If you want it to toggle back and forth, then you'll need to add additional logic.  The attribute value won't change. Instead you'll need to read the DOM property `elem.checked`.